# Flask + Peewee error AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'compiler'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, peewee

**What am I doing?**
I had been learning from a Flask tutorial (https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/)  and I'm stuck on the ORM section as it uses SQLAlchemy and I want to use Peewee (I use it in another project, and had been working nicely on it).

**Noob Problematic**
After configuring Peewee and define a BaseModel, and implementing it in a `User` model, I tried to do a query and got this error instead:

```
File "/home/atrevino/.local/share/virtualenvs/comparteme-qStpFUrM/lib/python3.6/site-packages/peewee.py", line 2932, in compiler
return self.database.compiler()   
AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'compiler'
```

Not sure if this is related to the configuration of my database, but I was able to get the MySQLDatabase object which makes me to think it's doing a connection to the DB properly.

The error above is displayed whenever I try to do something with Peewee's models, for example `User.get(User.id == 1)` or `User.create(username='Name')`

This is my test-app and environment configuration

`./config.py`

```
import os                            

class Config(object):
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or 'you-will-never-know'
    DATABASE = {
        'name': 'comparteme',                        
        'engine': 'peewee.MySQLDatabase',            
        'user': 'root',
        'password': 'whatever',                
        'host': os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or 'mysql://root@localhost:3306'
    }
```

`comparteme/__init__.py`

```
import peewee

from flask import Flask
from config import Config

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)

db = peewee.MySQLDatabase(app).database

from comparteme import routes
```

`comparteme/models/base_model.py`

```
import peewee
from comparteme import db


class BaseModel(peewee.Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db


class User(BaseModel):
    username = peewee.CharField(unique=True)
```

I call all this from a flask route:

`comparteme/routes.py`

```
from comparteme import app 
from comparteme.models.base_model import User


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    User.create(username='Alan')
    return 'returning any string'
```

To be able to test I have one `test.py` on my root directory that I added to FLASK_APP environment variable by using `export FLASK_APP=test.py`.

`./test.py`

```
from comparteme import app
```

After that I just do a regular `flask run` and open a browser with `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` and get the error.

Is this the correct way to configure Peewee?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: MySQLDatabase() does not accept a Flask app as it's initializer. It accepts a database name and connection info.